# How to apply negative condition to istio URI regex pattern

Tags: regex, go, istio, re2, istio-gateway

I'm trying to apply a negate condition along with allowed URIs through Istio gateway.

**Allowed:**

- /guest/*
- /guest/profile
- /guest/address

**Not Allowed:**

- /guest/v2 [anything that goes v2 after guest]
- /guest/v2/profile
- /guest/v2/address

**Question**
How exactly do we specify in the istio virtual service that it should not forward any v2 traffic but just others? I tried something like this `guest/(?:[^v\W]|v[^2\W])\w*` this for sure avoids the `guest/v2` prefix but not working others like `/guest/address/list`

```
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:        
            regex: guest/(?:[^v\W]|v[^2\W])\w*
      route:
        - destination:
            port:
              number: 8080
            host: my-guest.svc
```

Comment: Maybe all you need is to append `$`? `guest/(?:[^v\W]|v[^2\W])\w*$`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Istio, wouldn't it be easier to add a routing rule that matches any `/guest/v2(/.*)?` paths, and fails the request by injecting an abort fault with an appropriate HTTP status (one of `400 Bad Request`, `403 Forbidden`, or `404 Not Found`) by injecting an abort fault?

That rule would have to match before the rule that handles the valid paths.

- https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/fault-injection/
- https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPFaultInjection